What is the contextual significance of the verbs "hear" and "follow" (in PIA) on Jesus' statements in John 10:27-29?
Text: John 10:27-29 (NET)

My sheep listen to my voice, and I know them, and they follow me. I
give them eternal life, and they will never perish; no one will snatch
them from my hand. My Father, who has given them to me, is greater
than all, and no one can snatch them from my Father’s hand.


The illustration was simple for the people Jesus sp0ke to.  Shepherds would bring their flocks to the same watering hole, and the flocks would intermix.  The shepherd would bring his sheep away from the watering hold by calling to them.  The sheep would recognize their shepherds voice and follow him. Often the closest we come to this today is with calling pets.  The present active indicative fits well with both the illustration and what it illustrates.  The present tense expresses continuous action especially used in a general sense here.  Continuous action can have several different forms, but what it definitely means is not just once.  Would we expect anything otherwise from sheep with a shepherd?

The shepherd had a full-time job tending his sheep. At night he called them from the hills and gathered them in a stone kraal. The sheep knew the shepherd’s voice well (Jn 10:3). Usually he walked ahead of them and they followed him everywhere, because he took them to the best pasture and watering-places.
--
Du Plessis, I. J. (1998). "The social and economic life of the Jewish people in Palestine in the time of the New Testament." In A. B. du Toit (Ed.), The New Testament Milieu (Vol. 2). Orion Publishers.

Jesus calls us through the Holy Spirit.

Nevertheless, I tell you the truth: it is to your advantage that I go away, for if I do not go away, the Helper will not come to you. But if I go, I will send him to you.  And when he comes, he will convict the world concerning sin and righteousness and judgment:  concerning sin, because they do not believe in me; concerning righteousness, because I go to the Father, and you will see me no longer; concerning judgment, because the ruler of this world is judged.
(John 16:7–11, ESV2016)


Thanks for the background information. To look deeper, how does the present indicative active form of "hear" and "follow"  contribute to the meaning of Jesus' statement, especially regarding the believers' life?

@ Sam, I added your question to my answer.  If you look at the different tenses for know, hear, and follow in John 10, they fit the meaning you would expect for what Jesus illustrated.

The key to understanding John 10:27 is the question that Jesus is answering which occurs in V24:

So the Jews gathered around Him and demanded, “How long will You keep
us in suspense? If You are the Christ, tell us plainly.”

Jesus then provides clear evidence that He is the Messiah/Christ in V25:

“I already told you,” Jesus replied, “but you did not believe. The
works I do in My Father’s name testify on My behalf.

Jesus then states the reason that those questioning Him do not, and will not believe that He is the Messiah/Christ in V26:

But because you are not My sheep, you refuse to believe.

Jesus then contrasts such people with those who do believe and thus, are Jesus' sheep/disciples in V27, 28:

My sheep listen to My voice; I know them, and they follow Me. I give
them eternal life, and they will never perish. No one can snatch them
out of My hand.

The implication is significant - Jesus defines what it means to be one of His sheep/disciples:

Jesus' sheep are those who listen/hear Jesus' voice.  Compare John 14:15 - "If you love Me, you will keep My commandments." And, John 15:14 - "You are My friends if you do what I command you." etc.
Jesus' sheep are those who follow Jesus' way.  Compare Rev 14:4 - "These are the ones who have not been defiled with women, for they are virgins. They follow the Lamb wherever He goes. They have been redeemed from among men as firstfruit to God and to the Lamb."  And, John 12:26 - "If anyone serves Me, he must follow Me; and where I am, My servant will be as well."  Matt 10:38 - "*And he who does not take his cross and follow after Me is not worthy of Me.
*"  See also Matt 4:20, 22, 8:22, 9:9, Mark 1:17, Luke 9:23, etc.  Indeed, in all but one instance, the verb ἀκολουθέω (akoloutheo) is used of following Jesus.


In John 10:27, the verbs “hear” and “follow” are in the present indicative active (PIA) form, which significantly impacts our understanding of Jesus’ statement. The present tense in Greek indicates ongoing, continuous action. When Jesus says, “My sheep hear my voice” and “they follow me,” He describes actions that are habitual and characteristic of His sheep. This means true believers are consistently listening to Jesus’ voice and following Him, reflecting ongoing intimacy and attentiveness rather than sporadic or opportunistic actions.
Continuous Relationship: The PIA form highlights the continuous nature of the believers’ relationship with Jesus. The term “voice” underscores that this relationship involves actively hearing and responding to His guidance. Continuous hearing and following define the identity of Jesus’ disciples, emphasizing a lifelong pattern of obedience.
This continuous aspect raises important considerations regarding certain doctrinal views on eternal security. While Jesus promises that His sheep “will never perish” and that “no one can snatch them out of His hand” (v. 28), the grammatical emphasis and the mention of “voice” highlight that this assurance is linked to the nature of the relationship between Jesus and His sheep. The continuous action of hearing and following illustrates the dynamic, intimate relationship that characterizes Jesus’ disciples, which is integral to understanding the assurance of eternal life. This implies that the security Jesus offers is for those who persist in their faith and discipleship. Some interpret this as evidence that true believers will persevere, while others see potential tension with the view that salvation, once granted, cannot be lost regardless of one's relationship with Jesus.
In summary, the grammatical aspects of “hear” and “follow” in John 10:27-29, especially with the inclusion of “voice,” underscore the continuous, habitual nature of believers’ actions. Hearing Jesus’ voice and following Him reflect an ongoing relationship crucial for understanding the assurance of eternal life and raise questions about how this relates to certain doctrinal views on eternal security and the nature of true discipleship.

When Jesus spoke those words about hearing and following him, it was winter-time and he was walking through the spectacular Temple in Jerusalem.  Jerusalem was thronging with people there for the festival of dedication (of the Temple).
Yet very recently they had demonstrated their spiritual blindness and deafness at Jesus' words of life, so they could dedicate what they liked, and celebrate everything they had dedicated, but Jesus went on to warn them that this Temple would be utterly destroyed. He even said they should ask that their flight from it would not be in winter (Matthew 24:20). Those who heard him and who followed him heeded that later warning and so escaped the horrific massacre by the Romans in 70 A.D.
That is a hallmark of people who recognize that Jesus is their good shepherd, and that they are his sheep; they know his words are truth and eternal life, which sink deep into their hearts so that they do whatever Jesus tells them to do. And how do they know what Jesus commands them to do? Because they recognize when he is speaking to them.
They know that Jesus spoke warnings against false shepherds who would come in for gain, but flee the moment danger arose, leaving the sheep without their protection. They know that Jesus has laid down his life for his sheep, and that he is the only 'door' for them  (John 10:11-15). Then he added:

"But ye believe not, because ye are not of my sheep, as I said
unto you. My sheep hear my voice, and I know them, and they follow
me: and I give them eternal life; and they shall never perish,
neither shall any [man] pluck them out of my hand. My Father, which
gave [them] me, is greater than all; and no [man] is able to pluck
them out of my hand. I and my Father are one. Then the Jews took up
stones again to stone him." John 10:26-30 A.V. Emphasis mine.

This is on-going hearing and following. And it is on-going eternal life. It starts at the point of putting faith in Jesus, and it is life that never ends. It is active because it is based on living faith which is belief in what Jesus told them, because of who he is. The action that proves this, is their following Jesus, as his disciples.
Many certainly grow weary along the hard paths they will have to tread while following their good shepherd. But that does not mean they are at risk of being dropped out of Jesus' and the Father's singular 'hand'. They cannot be plucked out of that divine grasp. But they can grow weary along the way. Doubts may begin to creep in. Yet that on-going voice of Christ continues to encouraging them or (when severe situations require it) to be disciplined so as to bring them back along the narrow way (Hebrews 12:6). This world offers many allurements to detract them from keeping on looking to Christ, the author and perfecter of faith (Hebrews 12:2) but taking one's eyes off Christ is not to lose one's salvation even though the person will suffer for that.
In summary, they hear Jesus' words in that on-going sense because they are his. And he is theirs. Given to him by the Father before all worlds. Their hearts and ears are circumcised by the Spirit in the midst of time. Thus they hear. Thus they believe. And thus they follow.
